# How to add a button or image to a vertical table header of scrollview?

Tags: cocoa, scrollviewer, nsscrollview

I have seen a lot of programs had some buttons or images in the vertical or horizontal scrollview table header or bottom and click it to invloke some events, But I have searched interface builder library and not found some widget I can used , how these programs to implement it ? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add just above the vertical scroll bar, see [-[NSTableView setCornerView:]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000118-BCIDGEBB).

To add to the left of the horizontal scroll bar, you'll need to subclass NSScrollView and (in addition to creating/configuring/adding the auxiliary view of your choice) override -tile. You'd call [super tile], then adjust the horizontal scroller to make room, then position the auxiliary view to taste.